# Unbounded slack variables in linear programming problem

Tags: linear-programming, simplex-method

I have a linear programming problem:

Maximise, $z = x_1 + x_2$

Subject to:

$$
x_1 + x_2 \ge 10
$$
$$
2x_1 + x_2 \le 40
$$
$$
x_1, x_2 \ge 0
$$

When I construct the simplex tableau adding 2 slack variables and 1 artificial variable we obtain the matrix of constraint $A$ to be:

$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x_1 & x_2 & s_1 & s_2 & a_1 \\
1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

with the z-row of our tableau being:

$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
-2M & -1 & 0 & 0 & M \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

Which will produce the correct result, however, I also want to check for unboundedness. I am following to detect this:

- if all the constraint coefficients in the column of any non-basic variable are zero or negative

In this case, the solution is unbounded toward $s_1$. But clearly, this is not true, we cannot maximise $s_1$ to infinity and still have a solution that satisfies constraint 1.

Therefore I am unsure what I have wrong here?

Comment: What do the M's in your z-row in a simplex tableau?

Comment: @callculus42 sorry I am not sure I understand your q?

Comment: Why $M$ in the table?

Comment: M represents a large value see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_M_method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tableau is not represented at a feasible point, since you still have a column for the auxiliary variable $a_1$.

By taking into account the auxiliary variable $a_1$, your LP is indeed unbounded:

The first constraint writes:
$$x_1+x_2 +s_1 - a_1 \geq 10$$

If you augment $s_1$, you can augment $a_1$ the same amount, so the first constraint will remain satisfied without touching $x_1$ and $x_2$.